# How do I load an image from a url into a picturebox?

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, picturebox

I am using windows form applications and am wondering how i can load this image http://legionrpg.archstudios.net/Images/226x192/Horde.png into my picturebox in my form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Turns out there's actually a property for picturebox's where you can enter a URL and it will load the image in there. Look in the properties and mess around to find the attribute.

I don't code in C++ anymore so I don't remember what the property is called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to send HTTP GET/POST request follow this article I skimmed through and it uses the right stuff.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5256/Classes-for-Writing-HTTP-Clients-in-C